# React Native Expo Android issue "Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0."

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, nx-monorepo

I am getting an issue in expo react native project when I try to run it on the android simulator using nx expo commands. The issue is

```
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
             - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
             - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a runtime)
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
             - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a runtime)
```

This the gradle and plugin version
[image]

This is the jdk version
[image]

This is the build gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    namespace 'org.sample.svg'
    defaultConfig {
        // detox-plugin-default-config
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        applicationId 'org.sample.svg'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
    }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
  }
}
```

Any directions on resolving the issue will be much appreciated. Please note this is a new project I created today, and I also get similar issues in previous projects I created as well. IOS works absolutely fine but the android is giving this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Please note this works absolutely fine when I run the project directly from android studio. I am getting this issue when I try to run using nx expo commands**

Comment: Did you get it working, by any chance? I am getting the same error message, but on Windows. I am not sure what direction to look into.